# Finding the closest visible vertex among line segments

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a set $S$ of line segments (possibly sharing endpoints) and a query point $q$, how fast can we find the closest visible endpoint from $q$? If $p$ is the closest visible endpoint to $q$, then, in this case, it means that the line segment $pq$ does not intersect with any other line segment in $S$.

I am trying to implement an efficient algorithm in CGAL. I have explored the nearest-neighbor and visibility structures from CGAL but could not conclude anything.

Comment: Please look for "2D Segment Voronoy Diagrams"

Answer (score 2):

I only noticed after posting that my first answer does not directly address your
specific question. So now my answer is in two parts.

(1) As suggested by @HEKTO, to find the *closest segment*,
you could first compute the Voronoi diagram:
[CGAL 2D Segment Voronoi Diagrams](https://doc.cgal.org/Manual/3.1/doc_html/cgal_manual/Segment_Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html).
Then next you need to perform point location within the (non-rectilinear) cells of the diagram.
That is also discussed, using "the segment Voronoi diagram hierarchy, a data structure suitable for fast nearest neighbor queries..."

---

[image]

 

<sup>CGAL figure.</sup>

---

(2) You specifically ask for the *closest segment endpoint*, which is not necessarily an endpoint of the closest segment:

---

[image: SegEndpts]

          

<sup>Point $x$ is closer to segments $1,2,3,4$ than to the closest endpoint $y$.</sup>

---

For this you might need to look at
"visibility constrained Voronoi diagrams":

> Aurenhammer, Franz, Bing Su, Y-F. Xu, and Binhai Zhu. "A note on visibility-constrained Voronoi diagrams." *Discrete applied mathematics* 174 (2014): 52-56.
>   [Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X14001693#br000120).

I haven't studied this paper enough to be certain it solves your problem.
And perhaps there is a way to efficiently move from the closest segment to
the closest segment endpoint.

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting something from CGAL which I can use right away. But it appears that there is none.